Get Playback Bar Time in Foxglove Extension
I am creating a new foxglove extension. In my extension I am using context.onRender and RenderState to handle the interaction between the user and the extension. I am interested in getting the time foxglove is showing in the playback bar.
Could you give me a hint on how to access the time in the playback bar?
I tried with RenderState.currentTime but it's undefined so I don't know where to take the time from.
